# Using a != statement with an edittext object in java?

Tags: android, string, if-statement, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

Im trying to create a button which when pushed reads the edittext box to

1. Make sure its not blank
2. Make sure its not the default text in this case "First Name".

However when the button is pushed it still preforms the action even if the edittext text is First Name or blank. Is there an easier way to do this? Also the toast are not made when the text is First Name or blank.

```
createp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) { 

                if (fname.getText().toString() != "")
                    if (fname.getText().toString() != "First Name"){

                            prefsEditor.putInt("user", 1);
                            prefsEditor.commit();

                    }


        if (fname.getText().toString() == "")
        {
                    Toast.makeText(createactivity.this, "You need a first name to create a profile!", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (fname.getText().toString() == "First Name")  {

            Toast.makeText(createactivity.this, "You need a first name to create a profile!", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



            }});





}
```

Comment: In java, you must perform string comparison with `equals` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if (!fname.getText().toString().equals(""))
    ...
```

Another example:

```
if (fname.getText().toString().equals("First Name"))
    ....
```